# Is it possible to get Video/Audio Input from the user using window mode?

Tags: html, neutralinojs

I tried to make an app that uses the user's camera and plays it back to them. It works fine on the browser mode but when I try to use the window method nothing works. Am I missing something or has this yet to be implemented? Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

  <style>
    #container {
      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      border: 10px #333 solid;
    }

    #videoElement {
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
  </div>
  <script>
  var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then(function (stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
      })
      .catch(function (err0r) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      });
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been implemented. I tried it and it works for me in these halcyon days of August 2021 (at least on my Windows machine, haven't tried it elsewhere).